# Is there a way to retrieve the object via url from array of array of objects, to perform axios operations(get,post,put,patch,delete)

Tags: arrays, object, multidimensional-array, axios, json-server

[image: json-server mock api]

```
const getOneEmployee = () => {
  axios.get("localhost:4000/employees/[[]]")
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

I tried to send array of objects(the objects only) separately to json-server so that only objects are sent over api to resource employees/(in db json employees = [] was written), but it makes multiple request when perform foreach loop. Also the appended the http url with [] to access array, did not work. Kindly help to suggest any solution

Comment: Please post code

Comment: const getOneEmployee = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/employees/[[]]")
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };



the nested array after employees is just the representation my question is about. kindly suggest, thanks.

Comment: The square braces in the url path look like a mistake.  Based on the image, how about just getting `.../employees` ?

Comment: the square braces is intentionally put, just to show where i like to do the operation. tried .../employees, its returning empty {}.

Comment: Please, share txt instead of imgs - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @ericmp, may i know text for which part?Thanks.<br/>
1.this is just mock api dbjson:
{
  "employees": [
    [
      {
        "id": "eid123",
        "login": "1234",
        "name": "test",
        "salary": "1600"
      },
      {
        "id": "eid213",
        "login": "43",
        "name": "tset",
        "salary": "1400"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
2. function to retrieve dbjson data:
const getOneEmployee = () => {
  axios.get("localhost:4000/employees/")
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};

Comment: @Vishvaa Which part? the part that appears in the image. edit the question and paste the json there instead of adding the code here in the comments section neither doing it as img